# Using Drupal and Feed, how do I make one page per feed?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have Drupal installed with CCK, Feeds, Views and ViewsAttach.

I have multiple feeds and I wish to render them on seperate pages i.e. BBC sport feed needs to have its own page and menu item, BBC news feed needs its own page and menu item etc.

I am aware that I need to use Views and ViewsAttach to do what I want but I am having a problem getting it to work. When I create content using a Feed I can see the items in the View items tab but they don't appear on the page - they all appear on the front page and not on the actual page for the feed. How do I get them to appear on the correct page?

I'm tearing my hair out with this one and being a total Drupal newbie is obviously not helping any.

James :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each of your feeds views you need to add the "Aggregator feed: Feed ID" filter and set that to the Aggregator Feed ID that corresponds to the feed you want shown.